# how to create scatter dotted graph in php?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

i getting issue create dynamic dotted graph in php  data fetch data base y-axis data ploat and x-axis date required but getting issue pls give me some hint or google line
 i am using this code but x-axis not display date

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'scatter',
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Height Versus Weight of 507 Individuals by Gender'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: Heinz  2003'
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                enabled: true,
                text: 'Height (cm)'
            },
            startOnTick: true,
            endOnTick: true,
            showLastLabel: true
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Weight (kg)'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: 100,
            y: 70,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF',
            borderWidth: 1
        },
        plotOptions: {
            scatter: {
                marker: {
                    radius: 5,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: true,
                            lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                        }
                    }
                },
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        marker: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                    pointFormat: '{point.x} cm, {point.y} kg'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Female',
            color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
            data: [[07/07/2004, 51.6], [07/026/2004, 59.0], [08/01/2004, 49.2], [08/26/2004, 63.0]]

        }]
        }]
    }); });
```

Comment: This: `07/07/2004` x-value should be a timestamp, in your case: `1089158400000`. Change them to timestamps and note that timestamp in JS is milliseconds based (multiply seconds from PHP by 1000).

Comment: You also need to specify an axis type of 'datetime' - it is not the default.

Comment: any example dotted graph pls send me link

Comment: Just use the code you posted with changes we suggested.